# How to show JQuery Dialog close button only in specific page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've disabled the close button ([x]) from JQuery dialogs by setting the CSS below on my styles.css file :

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    display: none;
}
```

That's fine, usually i don't want the close button to show up. BUT in some specific situations, i want it to appear and what i'm trying to do is remove this CSS property via JS , using the command below :

```
$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').removeClass('display');
```

But for some reason it's not working. The only way to get back the close button is by removing the CSS attribute from my styles.css file.

Is there any workaround that does not require i write another CSS file specific for the page i want the button appear ?

Thanks

Comment: `$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').show()`

Comment: You are removing a class called display, not the actual display:none property. Maybe you can use removeProp('display')

Comment: @PranavCBalan This worked, you can add answer and i'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To hide it:**

```
$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').css("visibility","hidden");
```

**To show it:**

```
$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').css("visibility","visible");
```

Answer (score 1):

[removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) is used to remove class and not the property.You can't remove the `css` property using it. You can update property in `jquery` like this

```
$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').css("display":"block");
```

If you want to remove a property in `jquery` you can do it like this

```
$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').css("display":"");
```

You can simply show the `icon` by using [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) function in jquery like this

```
$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').show()
```

```js
$( "#close" ).click(function() {
  $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').show() 
});
```

```css
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="close">close</button>
<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close">Close Button Clicked</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to the body on the pages you want it to appear like that :

```
<body class="show-close">
```

And in your CSS file something like that :

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    display: none;
}

.show-close .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
    display: block;
}
```